# Allow system user (_gogs) to use ssh

Tags: macos, sshd

I have created a system user for gogs using [mkuser](https://github.com/freegeek-pdx/mkuser) for the dogs git server.

I have ssh setup but discovered that when I login it closes the connection.

Looking at the console I see this error: `fatal: Access denied for user _gogs by PAM account configuration [preauth]`

Could someone please help.

Answer (score 1):

macOS checks users that are logging in to sshd have a login shell specified in `/etc/shells`.

Gogs makes authorised key files that restrict ssh to a specific command. Therefore it's safe to set the login shell of `_gogs` to `/bin/sh` which solves the problem.